# Normal form definitions

Tags: normalization

I've had trouble finding a straight definition of normal forms online.

I don't want any examples or metaphors, just what each form is defined by in a nice format ! I believe there is more than 4 normal forms so it would be greatly appreciated if you could provide the extra information.

Please complete any missing information I've found or lay it out in a better format :

1FN:

- Each cell is to be single valued
- Entries in a column must be of the same type
- Rows must be uniquely identified

2FN:

- All attributes must be dependent of the key

3FN:

- Rows must be uniquely identifiable only by the key

4FN:

- No multi-valued dependencies

Comment: A simple Wikipedia search yields a very good explanation along with examples.  Look under 'List of Normal Forms'.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I am trying to make some quick reminder of what normal forms are constituted of. Something that is efficient to read and covers all of it, sure there is plenty to be learned from the 10+ pages of content on wikipedia but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this site helpful, too. I think it only goes up to 3NF, however it uses very good examples and clear language:

http://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/

> - **First Normal Form** – The information is stored in a relational table and each column contains atomic values, and there are not repeating groups of columns.
> - **Second Normal Form** – The table is in first normal form and all the columns depend on the table’s primary key.
> - **Third Normal Form** – the table is in second normal form and all of its columns are not transitively dependent on the primary key

Answer (score 1):

@A_V, I think you can find what you're looking for [here](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm). It has explanations of 1NF - 4NF, including BCNF.

From the page:

> First normal form (1NF) sets the very basic rules for an organized database:
>
> Eliminate duplicative columns from the same table.
>
> Create separate tables for each group of related data and identify each row with a unique column or set of columns (the primary key).
>
> Second normal form (2NF) further addresses the concept of removing duplicative data:
>
> Meet all the requirements of the first normal form.
>   Remove subsets of data that apply to multiple rows of a table and place them in separate tables.
>   Create relationships between these new tables and their predecessors through the use of foreign keys.
>
> Third normal form (3NF) goes one large step further:
>
> Meet all the requirements of the second normal form.
>   Remove columns that are not dependent upon the primary key.
>
> The Boyce-Codd Normal Form, also referred to as the "third and half (3.5) normal form", adds one more requirement:
>
> Meet all the requirements of the third normal form.
>   Every determinant must be a candidate key.
>
> Finally, fourth normal form (4NF) has one additional requirement:
>
> Meet all the requirements of the third normal form.
>   A relation is in 4NF if it has no multi-valued dependencies.
>
> Remember, these normalization guidelines are cumulative. For a database to be in 2NF, it must first fulfill all the criteria of a 1NF database.